# What is overwatch in python and flask?

Tags: python, import, flask

`app.py`:

```
from overwatch import app
app.run()
```

`__init.py__`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'Hello, World!'
```

What is `from overwatch import app` in a python flask app and how do I use it? There is no package to install for overwatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the name of the app for whatever example you're taking this from. It's not a Python package.

E.g. the contents of the directory structure with the above code mentioned would be...

```
app.py
overwatch/
    __init__.py
```

And thus `from overwatch import app` is actually just importing the `app` variable declared in the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just not used to python yet but I'm getting there.

Answer (score 0):

`overwatch` is the name of the Flask application (if you separate the running/testing code from the server code). Larger Flask projects are structured somewhat like this:

```
app_name/
  manage.py
  app/
    __init__.py
    models/
    views/
    ...
  ...
```

In your case, the `app` folder is named `overwatch`.